# Linux GPU selection while keeping display

Tags: gpu

I am trying to use AMD GPU, through a server Ubuntu system. Every time I execute the command export DISPLAY=:0 to switch from the integrated GPU to the AMD one, but at the same time, my display also switched from my local one to nothing. I wonder what's a command to keep my localhost and switch the GPU I am using on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; you mention server & Ubuntu, but haven't said if this is a Ubuntu Server system, or a Ubuntu Core Server system though both expect to be used *headless* so video card/GPU makes little sense as they aren't intended for graphics.

Comment: Also `DISPLAY=:0` is not a command "to switch from the integrated GPU to the AMD one".

Comment: where should I find the OS & release details? I have already run a Vulkan program and saved the result as a screenshot on this Ubuntu 20.04 system that doesn't have a desktop.

Comment: I am also starting to think my question isn't a valid one. I start to think that the displays are bounded together with the LLVMPIPE or AMD GPU, so it might not make sense to keep my localhost display while changing my GPU.

Comment: Your product/release can be obtained in many ways; eg. `lsb_release -a` and will show base system details and the answer is something like Ubuntu 20.04 Server, but details as to Desktop (with GUI) or Server (no GUI) are not shown with linux_standard_base commands (lsb)